# Opening dropdowns to be 100% height of the window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a filtering app that I am making and it utilizes a sidebar for the filtering options. Currently I have it so if they open, they take up a certain about of space, but would like it to be when they open, the unopened tabs sit at the bottom of the window.

So if I were to open the first tab it would look something like this

```
 __________
|__BRANDS__|
| Brand 1  |
| Brand 2  |
|          |
|          |
|__________|
|_FILTER 2_|
|_FILTER 3_|
|_FILTER 4_|
|_FILTER 5_|
```

(I hope that diagram makes sense)

Then if I were to open, say `filter 2` I would want it like this:

```
 __________
|__BRANDS__|
|_FILTER 2_|
| EFFECT 1 |
| EFFECT 2 |
|          |
|          |
|__________|
|_FILTER 2_|
|_FILTER 3_|
|_FILTER 4_|
|_FILTER 5_|
```

That way any of the unused ones (below the used one) get pushed to bottom of the browser.

Right now, I have it set up like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="filter-sect">
    <div class="collapse">
        <p class="heading">Brands ({{countUniqueBrands()}})</p>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse">
        <p class="heading">Percolator</p>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse">
        <p class="heading">Color</p>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.collapse{
  width:100%;
}

.container {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:500px;
}

.heading {
margin:0px;
color:#9c9c9d;
padding:7px 28px;
cursor:pointer;
position: relative;
font-size:17px;
font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:200;
}

.heading:hover{
  color:#FFF;
  background:#a8a8a7;
}

.active-tab, .active:hover{
  background:#FFF;
  color:#54ac51;
  font-size:20px;
  border-top:#dddddc 1px solid;
  border-bottom:#dddddc 1px solid;
  width:100%;
}

.content {
padding:15px 10px 10px;
  background:#e5e5e4;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.heading').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active-tab');
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide();

  $(".heading").click(function()
                      {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(450);
  });

});
```

Also, for those who like hands on, here is a downsized **[js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72kcvamq/)** and the **[codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/full/RNyYmz/)** that I am working in currently.

---

I tried a few things, mostly relating to wrapping the `divs` that open in another `div` then setting a height to that div, and telling the opened divs to be `height:100%` or `height:100vh`.

Nothing has really been working on figuring this out so any help you guys can give me to point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: seems like you are looking for an accordion functionality... i think their are numerous plugins out there if you are into that

Comment: Wouldn't what I currently have be considered an accordion? I am personally trying to keep this as much hard code as I can, so plug ins wouldn't be up my alley at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand. do you want the tabs to be 100% of the viewport? If its 100% then the opened one would overlap everything else, so I dont undestand.

Comment: @NachoDawg The left filtering menu will not scroll, so I would want the opened tag to be as tall as possible without pushing the tabs below it out of the viewport/viewing area. I saw a site with a similar functionality, I will try to find it and post it as an example. (I know it was some docs for a framework, let me check).

Comment: Is [this](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) what you want? An accordion, just full height, right?

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes! That is exactly what I'm looking for, just full height.

Comment: So, I would suggest the same thing as Epoch : just use one of the many accordions plug-ins out there. They're robust and easy to implement. And set your accordion `height : 100%`, and you're done. I didn't get why you refuse to use plugins?

Comment: Not necessarily refuse, but I've had a few sites where I build something, then the author of the plugin just let's it depreciate, then I get a client calling me about it. lol.

If I just need jqueryui, I can work with that since that whole library is well managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest part is finding the height-value of the available space to expand a menu-item in.

The reason this is so hard is that your menu is as high as the browser window, and browser sizes vary a whole lot between users and devices. The only way i know to solve this is using a kind  of costly functions `scroll` and `resize`.

```
var  closedTabHeight = 20, //This is a static number that works if all your tabs are of equal height in closed position
    closedMenuHeight = closedTabHeight * $('.collapse').length, //height times amount of tabs
    availableHeight= $(window).height - closedMenuHeight;

$(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
   availableHeight= $(window).height - closedMenuHeight;
   setMenuHeight(); //this one explained below
});
```

this leaves you with a number you can apply to the opened tab. But since we need to change the opened-tab height both when a click happens AND when the window resizes, lets put all that in a function which we call on both `resize`, AND `click`.

```
function setMenuHeight(){
   $('.active-tab').css('height', availableHeight);
}

$(".collapse").click(function(){
    setMenuHeight(); // makes sure the active tab gets the right height

    var thisContent = $(this).find('.content');

    if($(thisContent).is(':visible')){
        $(thisContent).slideUp(450); //close the tab if its the one already open

    }else{
        $('.content:visible').slideUp(450);
        $(thisContent).slideDown(450);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's almost there, you lost me on the `var` part, care to expand? Also added `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
});` so the content tabs are hidden on load.

Comment: I improved my answer for you

Comment: I inputed the code and no dice :/ not sure what I'm not understanding.
[codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/full/RNyYmz/) Here is where I'm at right now

Comment: Update: I was able to get it working using your code, thanks @NachoDawg!